# Modifying the Powershell calculated property with directory size

Tags: powershell

I am trying to modify the below script to add one more column 'Directory size' so that it shows the total directory size for NTFS share.

```
Function Get-SmbSharePermission([String]$ComputerName = '.') {
   $Shares = @{}
   Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {$Shares[$_.Name] = $_.Path}
   Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting -ComputerName $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
      $Name = $_.Name
      $_.GetSecurityDescriptor().Descriptor.DACL | Select-Object -Property `
         @{n='ComputerName'; e={$ComputerName}},
         @{n='Name'; e={$Name}},
         @{n='Path'; e={$Shares[$Name]}},
         @{n='Account'; e={"$($_.Trustee.Domain)\$($_.Trustee.Name)".Trim('\')}},
         @{n='Permission'; e={
            Switch ($_.AccessMask) {
               0x001F01FF   {'Full'}
               0x001301BF   {'Change'}
               0x001200A9   {'Read'}
               default      {"0x$($_.ToString('X8'))"}
            }
         }},
         @{n='Type'; e={If ($_.AceType) {'Deny'} Else {'Allow'}}}
   }
}
Get-SmbSharePermission | ogv
```

The script above does almost everything, except the total size of the directory.

How can I integrate it with the below function that can show the directory size?

```
$scriptBlock = {
   param ([string]$Path,
      [string]$GroupName)
   # Get the total directory number and file counts
   # the '/L' [for List] tells robocopy to not do anything, just list what it _would_ do
   #    /E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
   #    /L :: List only - don't copy, timestamp or delete any files.
   #    /NFL :: No File List - don't log file names.
   #    /NDL :: No Directory List - don't log directory names.
   #    /NP :: No Progress - don't display percentage copied.
   $RC_Results = robocopy $Path 'NULL' /L /E /NP /NFL /NDL
   
   # check to see if i forgot to re-enable the robocopy run [*blush*] 
   if ($RC_Results.Count -eq 0)
   {
      Write-Warning "You need to remove the `#` on line 2."
      break
   }
   
   # the summary table is the first 5 of the last 7 lines
   $RC_Summary = $RC_Results |
   Select-Object -Last 7 |
   Select-Object -First 5
   
   # add a 'Type' column header to the 1st line
   $RC_Summary[0] = 'Type' + $RC_Summary[0]
   
   # add placeholders for the blank 'Times' [last line] columns 
   $RC_Summary[-1] = $RC_Summary[-1].
   Insert(39, 'N/A').
   Insert(49, 'N/A')
   
   $NewRC_Summary = @()
   
   # line cleanup
   foreach ($Line in $RC_Summary)
   {
      # remove leading and trailing spaces
      $NewLine = $Line.Trim()
      # remove ':' that are NOT in time spans
      $NewLine = $NewLine.Replace(' :', '')
      # replace multi-spaces with singletons
      $NewLine = $NewLine -replace '\s{2,}', ' '
      # remove space between number and unit letter [bytes, kilobytes, etc.]
      #    1.22 m >> 1.22m
      $NewLine = $NewLine -replace '(\d)\s([bkmg])', '$1$2'
      # replace remaining spaces with a comma
      $NewLine = $NewLine.Replace(' ', ',')
      # add to the new summary collection
      $NewRC_Summary += $NewLine
   }
   
   $RC_SummaryTable = @{ }
   foreach ($Item in ($NewRC_Summary | ConvertFrom-Csv))
   {
      $RC_SummaryTable.Add($Item.Type, $Item.Total)
   }
   
   [PSCustomObject] @{
      DirPath        = $Path
      DirCount    = "{0}" -f $RC_SummaryTable['Dirs']
      FileCount    = "{0}" -f $RC_SummaryTable['Files']
      TotalSize    = "{0}" -f $RC_SummaryTable['Bytes']
   }
}
```

### Update

The suggested code by Cpt. Whale below shows the whole disk drive size not each directories under Path:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use volume information rather than doing a complete file listing via robocopy. I'm using the newer CimInstance powershell cmdlets here to get the volume information via `Get-SmbShare`:

```
Function Get-SmbSharePermission([String]$ComputerName = '.') {

    # Create a cim session to use later, and get a list of the remote share objects:
    $cim    = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computername
    $shares = Get-SmbShare -CimSession $cim | Where Name -NotIn 'print$','IPC$'

    # Iterate through each share
    Foreach ($Share in $shares) {
    
        # Skip shares without volume info (not file shares, e.g. shared printers)
        if(!$Share.Volume){continue}

        # Get the assoviated volume size
        $Volume = Get-Volume -CimSession $cim -UniqueId $Share.Volume
    
        # Get the access information, and format
        Get-SmbShareAccess -CimSession $cim -Name $Share.Name | Select `
            @{n='ComputerName'; e={$ComputerName}},
            @{n='Name';         e={$Share.Name}},
            @{n='Path';         e={$Share.Path}},
            @{n='Account';      e={$_.AccountName}},
            @{n='Permission';   e={$_.AccessRight}},
            @{n='Type';         e={$_.AccessControlType}},
            @{n='Drive';        e={$Volume.DriveLetter}},
            @{n='TotalSize';    e={[String][Math]::Round($Volume.Size/1GB)+' GB'}},
            @{n='FreeSpace';    e={[String][Math]::Round($Volume.SizeRemaining/1GB)+' GB'}}
    }
}

# Output:
Get-SmbSharePermission | ft

ComputerName Name   Path       Account                  Permission  Type Drive TotalSize FreeSpace
------------ ----   ----       -------                  ----------  ---- ----- --------- ---------
RemoteServer ADMIN$ C:\WINDOWS BUILTIN\Administrators         Full Allow     C 100 GB    20 GB    
RemoteServer ADMIN$ C:\WINDOWS BUILTIN\Backup Operators       Full Allow     C 100 GB    20 GB    
RemoteServer ADMIN$ C:\WINDOWS NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE       Full Allow     C 100 GB    20 GB
```

Comment: Hi @Cpt. Whale, thank you for the reply, yes, it is almost working as expected, however the TotalSize only captures the whole disk volume not each respective directory size from Each Path ?